# Help me please with translation 人の身で灯り

Tags: translation

Full sentence: **人の身で灯りも無く**深夜の森を行くのはあまりに過酷な作業である。
Thank you very much for your help.

[image]

Comment: Please note the entry in our [FAQ](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-should-i-format-my-questions-on-jlu/808#808) entry for help on formatting questions. The markdown bug that prevents bolding text from working correctly is addressed there.

Comment: This question would be better if the person asking the question gave some idea of what their attempt at a translation was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not parsing your sentence correctly. It should be

> *人の身で* **灯りも無く** 深夜の森を行くのはあまりに過酷な作業である。 
>   *A living human being* going to the woods late at night **without a light** is quite a serious undertaking.

where the bold and italic parts correspond to one another.

Comment: This「人の身で」is like「人の体で」「人間の体で」「[生身]{なまみ}の人間でありながら」. (ググったけど辞書には例が無くて。で、こんな例文しか見つかりませんでしたが。。。 https://twitter.com/TheLastWill/status/6489503487 )
「人の如き影...」というふうに「（人であるとの）断言をはばかるのは...」と述べる理由ですので。

Comment: So then we cannot translate "人の身で" as "oneself"... or can we ?

Comment: Maybe "Going to the woods as human..."? It would help, if you gave some context from your video game.

Comment: @user1205935 もう少し口語的な日本語にすると多分...「生身の(or生きている)人間が、明かりも持たないで、深夜の森を~~」という感じになると思います。(つまり主語みたいな感じ‌​です)